# Update Core Data Object Order - Not Working

Tags: swift, uitableview, core-data

**Current Behavior**

My core data keeps track of the values for a UITableView list. Each row has a title and description. My core data is working for appending new records and later deleting them. Core data is also working great for editing the content of the existing records.

**Problem/Question**

I just added drag and drop functionality in the table. On the surface, it works perfectly. I can drag the top item to the bottom, middle to the top, etc. However, the new list order does not persist after app shutdown because the Core Data records aren't being updated.

I found a few tutorials on this but none seem to work with my code. I also spent a few hours trying to use and adapt my current Core Data skill set (update, delete, edit) to invent a solution. I have no sweet moves or code kung fu.

Should you choose to accept this mission, below are the details and code you might need.

**Information**

Coding in Swift

Using X-Code 6.4

Core Data Info:

File name is: CD_Model

Entity name: TodayTask

Attribute names: "name" and "desc"

**Code:**

Main list variable:

```
var todayTaskList = [NSManagedObject]()
```

ViewDidLoad for main list page with UITableView

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    //Break

    //Load the list from Core Data
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName:"TodayTask")
    var error: NSError?
    let fetchedResults = managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &error) as? [NSManagedObject]

    if let results = fetchedResults {
        todayTaskList = results
    } else {
        println("Could not fetch \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
    }

    //Break

    //This provides a variable height for each row
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 80.0

    //Break

    //Part of code for cell drag and drop functionality
    let longpress = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "longPressGestureRecognized:")
    tableView.addGestureRecognizer(longpress)
}
```

Table Setup

```
//***** ----- ***** ------ ***** ----- ***** ----- *****
//Table View & Cell Setup
//***** ----- ***** ------ ***** ----- ***** ----- *****
@IBOutlet weak var name_Label: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var desc_Label: UILabel!

//Tells the table how many rows it should render
//*Looks to the Core Data NSObject to count tasks
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return todayTaskList.count
}

//Creates the individual cells. If the above function returns 3, this runs 3 times
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    //Setup variables
    let cellIdentifier = "BasicCell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
    let task = todayTaskList[indexPath.row]

    //Create table cell with values from Core Data attribute lists
    cell.nameLabel!.text = task.valueForKey("name") as? String
    cell.descLabel!.text = task.valueForKey("desc") as? String

    //Make sure the row heights adjust properly
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 80.0

    return cell
}
```

And here is where my problem is, the drag and drop. This code works, **but it is missing code that rearranges the core data.** Without that code, any drag/drop re-ordering will reset when I close the gap:

```
   //This function initiates the Drag & Drop code.
    func longPressGestureRecognized(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {

        let longPress = gestureRecognizer as! UILongPressGestureRecognizer
        let state = longPress.state

        var locationInView = longPress.locationInView(tableView)
        var indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(locationInView)

        struct My {
            static var cellSnapshot : UIView? = nil
        }
        struct Path {
            static var initialIndexPath : NSIndexPath? = nil
        }

        let currentCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!) as! CustomTableViewCell;

        var dragCellName = currentCell.nameLabel!.text
        var dragCellDesc = currentCell.descLabel.text


        //Steps to take a cell snapshot. Function to be called in switch statement
        func snapshopOfCell(inputView: UIView) -> UIView {
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(inputView.bounds.size, false, 0.0)
            inputView.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())
            let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() as UIImage
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
            let cellSnapshot : UIView = UIImageView(image: image)
            cellSnapshot.layer.masksToBounds = false
            cellSnapshot.layer.cornerRadius = 0.0
            cellSnapshot.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(-5.0, 0.0)
            cellSnapshot.layer.shadowRadius = 5.0
            cellSnapshot.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.4
            return cellSnapshot
        }


        switch state {
            case UIGestureRecognizerState.Began:
                //Calls above function to take snapshot of held cell, animate pop out
                //Run when a long-press gesture begins on a cell
                if indexPath != nil {
                    Path.initialIndexPath = indexPath
                    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!) as UITableViewCell!
                    My.cellSnapshot  = snapshopOfCell(cell)
                    var center = cell.center

                    My.cellSnapshot!.center = center
                    My.cellSnapshot!.alpha = 0.0

                    tableView.addSubview(My.cellSnapshot!)

                    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.25, animations: { () -> Void in
                        center.y = locationInView.y

                        My.cellSnapshot!.center = center
                        My.cellSnapshot!.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.05, 1.05)
                        My.cellSnapshot!.alpha = 0.98

                        cell.alpha = 0.0

                        }, completion: { (finished) -> Void in

                            if finished {
                                cell.hidden = true
                            }
                    })
                }
            case UIGestureRecognizerState.Changed:
                //Runs when the user "lets go" of the cell
                //Sets CG Y-Coordinate of snapshot cell to center of current location in table (snaps into place)
                //If the indexPath is not 0 AND is not the same as it began (didn't move)...
                //Update array and table row order
                var center = My.cellSnapshot!.center
                center.y = locationInView.y
                My.cellSnapshot!.center = center
                if ((indexPath != nil) && (indexPath != Path.initialIndexPath)) {

                    swap(&todayTaskList[indexPath!.row], &todayTaskList[Path.initialIndexPath!.row])
                    tableView.moveRowAtIndexPath(Path.initialIndexPath!, toIndexPath: indexPath!)

                    Path.initialIndexPath = indexPath

                }
            default:
                //Runs continuously as there's a long press recognized?
                //Animates cell movement
                //Completion block: 
                //Removes snapshot of cell, cleans everything up
                let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(Path.initialIndexPath!) as UITableViewCell!
                cell.hidden = false
                cell.alpha = 0.0
                UIView.animateWithDuration(0.25, animations: { () -> Void in
                    My.cellSnapshot!.center = cell.center
                    My.cellSnapshot!.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
                    My.cellSnapshot!.alpha = 0.0
                    cell.alpha = 1.0
                    }, completion: { (finished) -> Void in
                        if finished {
                            Path.initialIndexPath = nil
                            My.cellSnapshot!.removeFromSuperview()
                            My.cellSnapshot = nil
                        }
                })
        }
```

I am pretty sure the code I need would go inside the second case statement:

```
case UIGestureRecognizerState.Changed:
```

I also think the code I need would start with something like...

```
var appDel: AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate)
var context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!
```

But then is there a special code for rearranging? Do I have to delete and insert? If so, how?

HUGE thanks in advance to anyone who can help resolve this one!

Comment: you need to use a FetchedResultsController for your tableview as well as an index of some sort for maintaining the sort order (position) and then when you drag and drop you need to create a new object (using the Core Data API's) with the correct index and you need to also update the other objects index (or sort order).  The TableView will update itself automatically to correctly reflect the order of the updated objects.

Comment: May I be appalled for a second at "X-Code"? Oh dear… This is worse than "xCode"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well first of all, you might find it easier to create classes for each entity so that you don't have to work with objects vaguely typed to `NSManagedObject` or read and cast with `valueForKey(_:)`.  In the solution below, I've included code samples for that.

So to solve your order problem, there are two things you could do:

1) Add a property that defines the order of your `Task` entity.  This can be a simple as an `NSNumber` called `displayOrder`.  Your fetch request can then order the results according to that property.  Then, when your table cells are re-arranged, iterate through the task list and update the `displayOrder` property of each task to reflect the order in which they are being displayed.  Save your managed object context and the next time your fetch request loads, it will order them accordingly.

[image]

```
class Task: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var name: NSString
    @NSManaged var desc: NSString
    @NSManaged var displayOrder: NSNumber
}

let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()
let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "displayOrder", ascending: true )
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [ sortDescriptor ]
```

2) Create a CoreData entity that represents a list with a to-many relationship that stores each task entity in an ordered set.  Then, when you add tasks to the set, they will be remain saved in the order you've added them.

[image]

```
class TaskList: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var tasks: NSOrderedSet?
}

class Task: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var name: NSString
    @NSManaged var desc: NSString
    @NSManaged var parentList: TaskList?
}
```

**Update to answer remaining questions:**

I highly recommend you use your own custom classes instead of `NSManagedObject`, but until you figure that part out here's what you can do to your code as is.

To update display order after rearranging or deleting:

```
func updateDisplayOrder() {
    for i in 0..<todayTaskList.count {
        let task = todayTaskList[i]
        task.setValue( i, forKey: "displayOrder" )
    }
}
```

To append a new task:

```
func addTask( task: NSManagedObject, displayOrder: Int ) {
    todayTaskList.insert( task, atIndex: displayOrder )
    updateDisplayOrder()
}
```

Comment: Hi Patrick, thank you. This sounds like a good solution. Problem is I'm brand new to Core Data (as of three days ago); I need to read a book on it but haven't yet. Currently, I can't write the code to now include an order attribute and maintain the correct value for each record. Could you give a few examples? Such as, when I append a new object, how do I perform a count of a Core Data list so I know what value to assign to the new object? Or how do I cycle through the list and assign all new values after a delete or rearrange? An example would go a LONG way.

Comment: That's a lot to explain, and I hesitate to add it here because it's outside the scope of this question.  But you'll have all those questions answered after a few chapters of a Core Data book.

Comment: Hey again, I'll probably go the book route if I can't find the code-answer searching online. I do think providing the code is within the scope of the "If so, how?" part of the question. I posted my code to show what I was doing and ask how to change it so table row order changes would persist. But it won't kill me to solve the rest myself; expecting the forums to do all the leg work is a bit lazy on my part. Thanks for the direction. When I do end up figuring out the code, if it fits your high level explanation I'll mark it correct at that time.

Comment: I've added an update.  Your code needs a lot of work, there are many fundamental problems and it hurts me to ignore them just to give you the snippets you want to get it working now.  But it hurts even more to be denied the points for correctly answering your question.  So, if you please...

Comment: First of all, thank you for appending suggested code. I did read a lot of Apple's Core Data guidebook today but apparently I'm still no expert. If you're willing to clear up a few last questions, I'd really appreciate it. I tried adding your updateDisplayOrder to my drag/drop code (which runs on a long press gesture change) and adding the addTask/updateDisplayOrder to my 'add new list item' code. I added context.save too. But drag/drop changes still don't persist after close. There are no errors during testing. Where's the sort descriptor (fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [ sortDescriptor ]) go?

Comment: In your code you are creating a fetch request under the comment `//Load the list from Core Data`.  Add it there.  Can you post a link to a repository so I can look in detail?

Comment: That did the trick. I really appreciate your patience. I will remember your advice on using classes instead of "obscure references" to NSMangedObject. Still don't fully understand the benefit except clearer code, but I do want to write good code.