# Saving the right row in a TableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, save, row

I`m a Beginner in swift and i have tried to build a shopping list app with a tableView in it. Nearly everthing works, except:
When you reorder the rows, quit the app, and going back, the new row order was not saved.
Any ideas?

This is the important part:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
    let movedObject = shoppingList[sourceIndexPath.row]
    shoppingList.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.row)
    shoppingList.insert(movedObject, at: destinationIndexPath.row)
}
```

But in will not work.....

Here is the whole code:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData


var shoppingList: [NSManagedObject] = [ ]


class ShoppingList_1: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

//Anzahl Spalten -->
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
}


//**************************
//Zeilen: dynamisch; abhängig von Anzahl items in Liste -->
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return shoppingList.count
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    let item = shoppingList[indexPath.row]
    let cell = Cell.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
    // <-- Prototype Cell für Ausschnitt/Sicht des Bildschirms

    cell.textLabel?.text = item.value(forKeyPath: "itemName") as? String
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "\(indexPath.row)"

    return cell

}
```

//free to use
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {  

   print("Daten geladen!\n")

    let movedObject = shoppingList[sourceIndexPath.row]
    shoppingList.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.row)
    shoppingList.insert(movedObject, at: destinationIndexPath.row)
    NSLog("%@", "\(sourceIndexPath.row) => \(destinationIndexPath.row) \(shoppingList)")
    // To check for correctness enable: self.tableView.reloadData()

}



//*****************************************************************************************************
//Durch wischen entfernen -->
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete
    {
        guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {return}

        let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        managedContext.delete(shoppingList[indexPath.row])



        do {
            try managedContext.save()

            shoppingList.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)


        } catch let err as NSError {
            print("12345", err)
        }
    }
}

@IBOutlet weak var AddButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var AddItem: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var Cell: UITableView!



@IBAction func EditTopRightButton(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
self.Cell.isEditing = !self.Cell.isEditing
    sender.title = (self.Cell.isEditing) ? "Done" : "Edit"
}


//Button Action
@IBAction func AddButton2_Test(_ sender: Any) {
 print("My test")
 let a:Float = 2
 let b:Float = 3
 let Ergebnis:Float = a+b
 print(Ergebnis)


 if (AddItem.text !=  "")
 {
    self.save(AddItem.text!)
 }


 Cell.reloadData()


}



override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {return}

    let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "Item")
    do {
        shoppingList = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
    } catch let err as NSError {
        print("Failed to fetch items", err)
    }


 }




func save(_ itemName: String){
        guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else { return }
        let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Item", in: managedContext)!
        let item = NSManagedObject(entity: entity, insertInto: managedContext)

        item.setValue(itemName, forKey: "itemName")

        do {
            try managedContext.save()
            shoppingList.append(item)
        } catch let err as NSError {
            print("Failed to save item",err)
        }

    }

   //*****************************************************************************************************
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    Cell.delegate = self
    Cell.dataSource = self
    AddItem.delegate = self       

}




//HINZU-->


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

}




//*****************************************************************************************************

// extensions -->
extension ShoppingList_1 : UITextFieldDelegate {
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    AddItem.resignFirstResponder()

return true
}
}

//***************************************
```

Answer (score 0):

**Current Working**

In your code, Table view is loaded with data from Coredata at `viewWillAppear`. Data inserted to core data is not updated when you change the order in TableView.

So even you changed order of cell and corder in Array. Every time `viewWillAppear` calls Data is again fetched from Coredata with no order.

`ViewWillAppear` will call every time view display in screen. Incase you are coming back to this view from any other presented view `ViewWillAppear` will call.

**Sollution**

You can create a new attribute in table describing order of item in Coredata Entity & Sort the item with this order after fetching.
Refer this answer to know how to set display order with core data
https://stackoverflow.com/a/31907857/4845644

Or If your requirement is just to persist order to ViewController instances existence you need to change core data fetch code from `viewWillAppear` to `viewDidLoad`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    Cell.delegate = self
    Cell.dataSource = self
    AddItem.delegate = self       
    guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {return}

    let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "Item")
    do {
      shoppingList = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
    } catch let err as NSError {
      print("Failed to fetch items", err)
    }
}
```